# How do I make a Container fill the whole page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get my container from react-bootstrap to fill the whole page both height-wise and width-wise. This is my CSS for my App.js:

```
.main-content{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
}
```

and here is the code inside my App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container className='main-content'>
      Hello World
    </Container>
  )
}

export default App
```

And when I load the webpage the page is filled height-wise but has some spaces in the width on the left and right:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put it inside `<Container>`. Bootstrap's container has `max-width` or `width` and `margin-left: auto;` `margin-right: auto` applied to it.

So, it does not fill page and is center aligned.

Do something like this:

```
<div className='main-content'>
  <Container>
    Hello World
  </Container>
</div>
```

Comment: ahhh I did not know this, thank you so much your knowledge is very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the width to `100vw`. Your component probably has a parent that doesn't fill the page.

Comment: That is all the code and components I have so far

Comment: Also I tried putting 100vw to the width and I still have those blank sides?

Comment: Have you investigated using your browser's inspector tool?